# How would I search for a model using an array in a .where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Let's say there is a model called User. That has the attribute :hobbies.

```
user = User.first
user.hobbies
=> ["Bowling", "Cooking", "Knitting"]
```

If I wanted to use a .where searching for the :hobbies attribute, how would I do that? I'm using postgresql, and

```
:hobbies, :text, array:true
```

User.where(hobbies: "Anything I put here, string array, hash") throws the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you can use any SQL you want by passing a string to `where`, e.g.:

```
User.where("hobbies @> ARRAY['Bowling', 'Cooking', 'Knitting']")
```

or

```
User.where("hobbies && ARRAY['Bowling', 'Cooking', 'Knitting']")
```

Postgres has good documentation of the [array operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html) available.

Comment: Would any of these translate into `WHERE hobbies IN('Bowling', 'Cooking', 'Knitting')`? 'Cos that would be the optimal query.

Comment: `COUNT` does not tell you the length of the array, but it tells you how many *rows* are getting rollup up in an aggregate query. That's why it's always giving you 1: no matter how long the array, there is still just one row. You probably want `array_length(hobbies, 1)`. But I'm not actually sure what you're trying to do, so I could be on the wrong track.

Comment: The reason you can't use `IN` here is because `hobbies` is not a string, but an array of strings. So you should use the array operators instead. `@>` means `hobbies` has all of `Bowling`, `Cooking`, and `Knitting`. `&&` means it has at least one of them.

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth: Thank you for point out the contains operator specifically. My query that I was using to understand the operators was poor, and you pointing out that operator gave me my "Aha!" moment that my query was all contained by the attribute. I got used to working with joins.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `contains` or `overlap` from [`postgres_ext`](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) gem. Just install the gem and then query:

```
query = ["Bowling", "Cooking", "Knitting"]

#With Overlap operator:
User.where.overlap(hobbies: query)

#or with Contains Operator
User.where.contains(hobbies: query)
```

Comment: undefined method `overlap' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x007fadef6c0b98>. Same goes for contains :l

Comment: Ah, my bad! You'd need [`postgres_ext`](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) gem for this to work.